# estimating the derivatives of $\sin z$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

> (a) Use Cauchy inequality to obtain estimate for the derivatives of $\sin z$ at $z=0$ and
>   (b) determine how good these estimates are

No examples are given except the proof on [Cauchy Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114349/how-is-cauchys-estimate-derived?rq=1). How do I work this out?

If I take $|z|=1$ as my circle, would $\displaystyle \max \left \{ \sqrt{\sin^2 x + \sinh^2 \left( \sqrt{1-x^2} \right) }\right \} n!$  be an approximation for my n-th derivative of $\sin z$ inside circle $|z| = 1 $?

Comment: a constant $M$ such taht $|f(z)|\leq M$

Comment: yes sorry!! ....

Comment: Note that, $M$ depends on $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first we look at a nice definition to estimate $M$. As we know 
$$\sin(z)=\frac{1}{2i} \left(\exp(iz)-\exp(-iz)\right).$$

So when $|z|\leq 1 $ we have $|\sin(z)|\leq 2 e$. In fact we should have something like 
$$|\sin(z)|\leq \frac{1}{2}\cdot \left( e-\frac{1}{e}\right),$$
which gives you the estimate that 
$$|\sin'(0)|\leq 2 e $$
If you take the radius of your circle smaller, the approximation will be better. I don't know if this is what your are looking for.

The idea is that when $f$ is analytic we can write $f$ as 
$$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$$
As we know that 
$$\sin(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}\pm \dots$$

So when $|z|\to 0$ we know that $|\sin(z)|$ goes to $0$ as fast as $|z|$. Hence we can chose $M$ to be something like $r$, maybe with minimal difference $\epsilon$.

With that one we would get the estimate 
$$|\sin'(0)|\leq \frac{(r+\epsilon) \cdot 0!}{r}\approx 1$$
which gives a nice estimate for the first derivative.

Comment: probably!! if we take $r \to 0$ wouldn't our estimate grow? this $r^n$ at denominator is bothering me!!

Comment: If we take the same $M$ our estimate would grow (in fact it would grow freaking fast). But with a lower radius we can bound our $M$ stricter and with that we should be able to get a better approximation (but for that we need a better $M$).

Comment: looks like we need $|\sin z|$ as $z \to (0,0)$

Comment: @MulaKoSaag added some details

Comment: I think $1!$ instead of $0!$, it seems okay for first derivative. any idea with higher derivatives?

Comment: oh right it is $1!$ sorry for that. For higher derivatives you get the same approximation but as you said the denominator will give no nice estimation. But well that is why it is called an approximation

Comment: ok ok .. thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

For example, by Cauchy:

$$f'(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\limits_C\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}dz$$

witn $\,C\,$ any simple, closed path containing in its interior the point $\,z_0\,$ and wherein $\,f(z)\,$ is analytic (say, $\,C=$ the unit circle for $\,z_0=0\,\;,\;\;f(z)=\sin z\;$ in our case), and since

$$\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}\implies|\sin z|\le\frac{1}{2}(e^{-Im(z)}+e^{Im(z)})\le\frac{1}{2}(e+e^{-1})$$

so again by Cauchy:

$$|\sin'(0)|=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\limits_C\frac{\sin z}{z^2}dz\right|\le\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint\limits_C\left|\frac{\sin z}{z^2}\right|\,dz\le\frac{1}{4\pi}\oint\limits_C\frac{e+e^{-1}}{1}dz=\frac{e+e^{-1}}{2}\sim 1.86$$