# Application of Cauchy's integral formula.

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f$ be an entire fundtion satisfying $|f^{\prime}(z)|\le 2|z|$ for any $z \in \Bbb C$. Then show that $f(z)=a+bz^2$ for some $a,b\in \Bbb C $ with $|b| \le 1$.

My trial : I tried to show that $f^{\prime\prime}(z)$ is bounded on $\Bbb C$.So, I tried to find relation between $f^{\prime}$ and $f^{\prime\prime}$. I mean, $|f^{\prime\prime}(z)|$ $\le$ {something with $f^{\prime}(z)$ product |z|} $\le R $ by using generalized Cauchy's integral formula. But, I failed... 
Further, I just thought it has to do with utilizing maximum modulus Theorem. But I had no idea of how to apply it.. Could anyone just give a few hints. it would be great help. Thansk!

Comment: You can definitely replicate [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480617/show-that-fz-a-1z/2480704#2480704)

Answer (score 3):

Two versions ...

---

Because $f(z)$ is entire, it has a [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Analytic_functions) 
$$f(z)=a_0+\sum\limits_{n=1}a_nz^n \tag{1}$$
$$f'(z)=a_1+\sum\limits_{n=2}na_nz^{n-1} \tag{2}$$
From
$$\left|f'(z)\right|\leq 2|z|, \forall z\in \mathbb{C} \Rightarrow |f'(0)|\leq 0$$
or
$$0=|f'(0)|=|a_1| \Rightarrow  a_1=0 \Rightarrow f(z)=a_0+\sum\limits_{n=2}a_nz^n \tag{3}$$
But then
$$\left|f'(z)\right|\leq 2|z|, \forall z\ne0 \Rightarrow \left|\sum\limits_{n=2}na_nz^{n-1}\right|\leq 2|z| \Rightarrow |z|\left|\sum\limits_{n=2}na_nz^{n-2}\right|\leq 2|z|\Rightarrow\\
\left|\sum\limits_{n=2}na_nz^{n-2}\right|\leq 2, z\ne0$$
or
$$\left|\sum\limits_{n=2}na_nz^{n-2}\right|\leq \max\{2,2|a_2|\}, \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$$
This means that $g(z)=\sum\limits_{n=2}na_nz^{n-2}$, which is entire, is also bounded. According to [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) $g(z)$ is constant. But $f'(z)=z\cdot g(z)=Cz$ or $f(z)=a_0+\frac{C}{2}z^2$ and the result follows ...

---

**An alternative approach** is to apply [Cauchy's estimate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114349/how-is-cauchys-estimate-derived) to $(2)$
$$a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \Rightarrow na_n=\frac{(f')^{(n-1)}(0)}{(n-1)!}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{C_R}\frac{f'(z)}{z^{n}}dz$$
leading to
$$|na_n|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{C_R}\left|\frac{f'(z)}{z^{n}}\right||dz|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{C_R}\left|\frac{2}{z^{n-1}}\right||dz|=\frac{2}{R^{n-2}}$$
Taking the $\lim\limits_{R\rightarrow\infty}$ we have $a_n=0,\forall n\geq 3$. As a result, considering $(3)$ too $$f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=1}a_nz^n=a_0+a_2z^2=a+bz^2$$

---

Last part, for $\forall z\ne 0$:
$$|f'(z)|\leq 2|z| \Rightarrow |2bz|\leq 2|z| \Rightarrow |bz|\leq |z| \Rightarrow |b|\leq 1$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** What can you say about the function 
$$\mathbb{C} \backslash {0} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}: z \mapsto \frac{f'(z)-f'(0)}{z}?$$